# Regular expression not returning everything on pattern in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm using https://regexr.com/ for testing the regex pattern with the following,

[image]

but when I try to use the same pattern in python I got

[image]

how can I rewrite the python pattern so I can retrieve the "state of " as in the regexr site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the whole string you want to capture into parentheses. Note that with multiple capture groups, the result will be a list of tuples (the first element of the tuple will be the first capture group):

```
import re
re.findall(r'state.*.(ny|new york)', 'consumption state of ny ')
```

`['ny']`

```
re.findall(r'(state.*.(ny|new york))', 'consumption state of ny ')
```

`[('state of ny', 'ny')]`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to match patterns such as `"state of ny"` or `"state that is named new york"`, you should put the entire string you want to capture into parentheses and use a non-capturing group for the alternative.

```
re.findall(r'(state.*.(?:ny|new york))', " consuption state of ny  ")
```

Additionally, `.*.` could be written as `.+` to be a little more concise.